# input buffer overflow, can't enlarge buffer because scanner uses REJECT

Tags: lex

While parsing a file with a large string of length 20000, I get the following error message

input buffer overflow, can't enlarge buffer because scanner uses REJECT

How can fix this in lex and yacc?

Thanks!

Comment: It's odd that your scanner would need to keep a 20,000-character buffer. Can you post your source code and a description of what you're trying to scan?

Comment: Sure - the following code generates 20000 character sequence - perl -e 'printf qq(string "%s"\n), "a"x20000' > test

Comment: I suspect that the only answer is "Don't use REJECT". Do you really need it?

Comment: @rici I have reproduced this error in a flex-generated scanner that positively does not use REJECT. The only reference to REJECT In the entire project is the `#define REJECT` in the `lex.yy.c` file, which is not used anywhere, and the mention of the word `REJECT` in the above diagnostic. :)